# Visual Studio Android App not launch on emulator

Tags: c#, android, emulation

I try to launch an android app on a visual studio emulator, and the emulator starts successfully, but the app doesent.
There is no error messgage, nothing app related in the visual studio build log.
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqIEw.png)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  Which emulator?  What research have you done?

Comment: Community 2015 Update 3;
Visual Studio Emulator for Android;
The same thing happens with any of the emulators